# Why would one React JavaScript file indent 4 spaces in VScode but all other files to 2

Tags: visual-studio-code

Probably the App.js file already existed and the others I created locally but why and how to fix it (make App.js use 2 space indentation like the other two .js files). A shown Shift-Ctrl-i makes it apply 4 space indents to the App.js file and 2 space indents to the two others.

I used a workaround of creating a new file "App2.js" and then copying and pasting the content into it.  When I then did a whole file format - Shift-Ctrl-i it applied the 2 space formatting that I wanted and that matches other .js files.  So then I renamed again and got App.js as a correctly indented for me (2 spaces) file.

So what is it about an existing file from someone else but still with a `.js` extension make it do this?

[image]

Comment: Check in the status bar, there is an indicator on space/tab indentation length, you can set it to what ever you want and then reformat

Answer (score 0):

does not help in current version of visual studio code on a mac. it usually changes to 4.

solution:

removed JS-CSS-HTML Formatter extension.